# How do I write function using reg ex through preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex

```
assert(isCorrect('') === true);
assert(isCorrect('()') === true); 
assert(isCorrect('{()}') === true);
assert(isCorrect('{()}{}') === true); 
assert(isCorrect('(())') === true);
assert(isCorrect('{({({({()})})})}') === true); 
assert(isCorrect('{(})') === false);
```

this i have result for preg_match:

```
function isCorrect($source){
    return (bool)preg_match('~^((\(([^)(}{]|(?1))*\))|\{(?3)*\})*$~', $source);
}
```

Now I have the same thing only through preg_replace();

Comment: You are already using `preg_replace`. And what is logic behind this?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please adjust your question.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: it looks like OP is trying to check with a regex if a string consisting of parens is "correctly nested". That is, all parens are closed in same (actually: reverse) order as they were opened.

Comment: I'm a little confused there.

Comment: @GordonFreeman you're not the only one who is confused, what exactly is your goal here?

Comment: You're looking for [recursive patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^((\(([^)(}{]|(?1))*\))|\{(?3)*\})*$` is the [recursive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) pattern [from my comment yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26002054/3110638) which [checks if the string is composed of correctly nested ({}) / {()}](http://regex101.com/r/qR8jL1/1) from `^` start to `$` end.

Assuming you want to replace all, that are correctly nested with empty string `""` change it to:

```
$str = preg_replace('~\(([^)(}{]|(?0))*\)|\{(?1)*\}~', "", $str);
```

[Test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/iN7lG5/1); [Test at eval.in](https://eval.in/198092); [Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Please rephrase your question, what acutally you're going to do, if that's not it.

Answer (score 1):

Doing recursion could be a little tricky.
For sure you have to account for balanced pairs separately or it doesn't work.

If you expect just characters (){}, this one.

```
 # '~(\((?:(?>(?1))|)\)|\{(?:(?>(?1))|)\})~'

 (                      # (1 start)
      \(
      (?:
           (?> (?1) )
        |  
      )
      \)
   |  
      \{
      (?:
           (?> (?1) )
        |  
      )
      \}
 )                      # (1 end)
```

Or, if you expect other characters besides (){} inside, this one.

```
 #  '~(\((?:(?>[^(){}]+)|(?1))*\)|\{(?:(?>[^(){}]+)|(?1))*\})~'

 (                           # (1 start)
      \(
      (?:
           (?> [^(){}]+ )
        |  
           (?1) 
      )*
      \)
   |  
      \{
      (?:
           (?> [^(){}]+ )
        |  
           (?1) 
      )*
      \}
 )                           # (1 end)
```